# How to make the browser execute a JS script before the browser parse the HTML markup?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to find a way to execute a JS script before the browser parse the HTML markup.

I already tried the traditional `defer` and `async`that come with HTML but it looks like it does not help me achieving what I'm trying to do.

The purpose of the script that needs to be executed before the browser parse the HTML markup is that I need to get the user to give some data before he/she gets to my website.

Is there a elegant way to achieve this ?

Comment: You'll have to parse some HTML before you can execute JS. Thats how browsers work. But if you want to 'secure' your website, JS isn't the best idea. Can you not just hide all the content with some CSS and make it visible when the data has been given?

Comment: ah ! that is a good ID ! I didn't think about proceeding that way ...

Comment: @putvande your solution works best for me.Thanks for the idea !

Answer (score 1):

There's preload scanner which parses markup before JS runs, and AFAIK it can't be disabled.

Because `document.write` could theoretically emit markup that changes meaning of the rest of the document, browsers *pretend* not to parse markup after the `</script>` tag. However, browsers actually parse the markup twice: once as "preload scanner" before any JS runs, and then second time after the script finishes.

If you're doing any hacks that change which resources are loaded on the page, you'll need to hack harder with `<noscript>` and `<link rel=preload as=…>`.

Comment: Thanks I will explore that idea as well

Answer (score 0):

Create a new HTML page that only contains your script. Once your script is done running, redirect the user to the page you want.